# Developing User Defined Functions in Excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, add-in

I am developing a User defined function in Excel using C# and Class library in VS 2010.
I followed the tutorial at [How to Create UDF in Excel using C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/12/01/273127.aspx)
The code works well and it gets Registered.I can see my AddIn in InstalledAddIN list.
However after clicking on the Insert Function button in the formula bar.  From the dialog of available formulas, “Or select a category” drop down box I cannot see my Function that I have built
I am using VS 2010(Admin mode) however excel is in guest mode.Does privileges has to do anything with it.??

Could Also anyone explain me how can i install my AddIn?
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Excel Dna](http://exceldna.codeplex.com/).It is an open source project used to integrate Excel with .NET
also check [Excel 2013 XLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687837.aspx)

Comment: With Excel-DNA you need no installation or registration to make your worksheet UDFs work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write Excel User Defined Functions using C# directly with my [ESharper](https://vlasovstudio.com/esharper/) add-in without additional files and registration.